# Using cursor to auto create tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

For fun I am messing with phpmyadmin to get myself familiarized with sql but I am stuck at a issue.  I am trying to make it so I can automate the organization of employees into tables based on department.  I have a procedure I have been working on to use a different table that lists all the departments into a cursor and uses the cursor to fill in the blanks of a create table as query.  But when I try to run the creation of the procedure phpmyadmin errors out saying

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '' at line 3

but in my code line 3 is just `BEGIN`.  What do I need to do to make this work?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE deptOrganize()
BEGIN
DECLARE counting INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE location VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR SELECT Department FROM departments;

OPEN curs1;

WHILE counting < 15 DO

    FETCH curs1 INTO location;
    CREATE TABLE location AS
    SELECT * FROM employees
    WHERE employees.Department = location ;

END WHILE;



END;
```

Comment: I find `DECLARE counting INT DEFAULT 0;` as number 3.

Comment: Why do you want to create separate tables for each department?!?

Comment: there is a blank line at the top not shown and I want to make it just as a exercise for myself i know it makes no sense to do so but I just trying to practice my sql skills

Comment: You need to use dynamic sql..

Comment: Error message tells that you forget about delimiter reassign.

Comment: Your lesson for the day:  Do _not_ create a bunch of 'identical' tables.  It is bad schema design and you be chastised in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a variable for the table name in `CREATE TABLE`. You have to create dynamic SQL with the `PREPARE` statement.

You also need to use the `DELIMITER` directive to change the query delimiter from `;`, so you can use that as the statement delimiter within the procedure.

And you forgot to increment `counting`, so you have an infinite loop.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE deptOrganize()
BEGIN
DECLARE counting INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR SELECT Department FROM departments;

OPEN curs1;

WHILE counting < 15 DO

    FETCH curs1 INTO @location;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE TABLE ', @location, ' AS
        SELECT * FROM employees
        WHERE employees.Department = ?') ;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @location;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET counting = counting + 1;

END WHILE;

END$$
```